# Smashing (dashing) not sending events on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, widget, webrick, dashing

My smashing dashboard works fine on my Mac, but when I run on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04, the events don't update the dashboard until I exit the dashboard. I read somewhere to try

```
rackup -p 3030 -s webrick
```

...but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the size of data that you're sending from server side? Can you try with a smaller sized data?

I experienced something quite similar a while ago. In the end, it turned out that either dashing or server sent events(which dashing relies on basically) were not being able to handle that amount of data for whatever reason...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Our local Mac Mini runs the Smashing dashboard and works fine when I view it from the Mac Mini desktop. When I access it remotely from my local machine the `/events` endpoint never returns any data.

However, if I launch [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) on my local machine then the dashboard loads fine. I can't be sure of the reason but perhaps Charles Proxy is flushing the connection and for some reason the Ruby Thin server which Smashing uses isn't doing this for remote connections by default.